# How to recognize the touch of a non regular sprite image?

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone

I have a sprite and if it is touched the touch should be recognized. I used the coordinates to do so. I took the coordinates (min x, min y, max x , max y)of the sprite image. But The sprite image is not a rectangular shape. So, even if I  touch the coordinates outside the sprite and inside the rectangular bounds the sprite is recognized.
But for my application I need only the sprite to be recognized. So, I have to take only the coordinates of the sprite, but it is not regular shape. I am using CCSprite in my program.

So, what can I do to  for only the sprite to be selected ? Which classes should use for this?
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try one of the following...

- Create a bounding box smaller than the absolute extents of the sprite image.  Yes it will be smaller than the sprite.  This will eliminate the dead space click detection of the sprite the trade off being parts of your sprite which look selectable won't be
- Use a circular bounding area to detect if the user has clicked on your sprite.  Again you will have the dead space problem in my first suggestion but the sphere may give you some better coverage area over the sprite giving you better results on touch detection

This is a standard problem in physics collision detection systems which often end up using circles or rectangles as their collision bodies.  I would go with the either a circle or rectangle smaller than the size of your sprite as your bounding area.  Going finer detail than that you could generate bounding area polygons.  This would however introduce a whole bunch of new issues and concerns.

Answer (score 1):

I am building a Cocos2D game right now and what I am doing is first I step through my sprites and see which sprites the touch hit (they overlap in my app)

Then, for each sprite hit I use [sprite convertTouchToNodeSpace] to get an X,Y co-ordinate inside the sprite, which I can use (although the Y axis is flipped) to reference the CGImage I created the sprite with.

If the pixel at the touch point is 'clear' ie alpha 0, then the sprite was not really touched, and I check the next sprite in the z-order to see if it has color where it was touched.

Sometimes I think I should be using a two color mask image to go along with each sprite, not the sprite image. But, I am mr. make it work, then make it fast.

I realise this is not super efficient, but I do not have very many sprites and I do this only for touches.